# How to add Group claim in the B2C user token?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

Currently we have an app registration in the Azure B2C tenant. We want to include the Group claim as part of the B2C user token.

Tried below approach

- Updated the app registration manifest to `"groupMembershipClaims": "All"`, but still don't see the group claim.
- Tried with the custom policy by adding the `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups"/>`.

So we have followed one of the approach with Technical Profile suggested in the MS ticket.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/groups/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_Groups.xml

But we see some issue around it. When the string Collection "Groups" we try to add to the attribute, then the claim doesn't seems to be coming as part of the token.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" />
```

Note:- We have tried with pointing the `string Collection` to a `Webhook` as input claim , we see the data as expected in the `webhook` request body.

Comment: https://damienbod.com/2021/09/06/using-azure-security-groups-in-asp-net-core-with-an-azure-b2c-identity-provider/

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: Azure AD B2C doesn't support group claim in the token as it does in Azure AD token configuration. You need to make use of Microsoft Graph API call.

- Azure AD B2C is handled via IEF to issue the token.
- Hence to get the group claim you have to add it as an output claim in custom policy.
- And you need to call Microsoft Graph API via custom policy to get the group claim as the output claim.

Use the below **Microsoft Graph API call via a RESTful Technical Profile** to get the user's group membership. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to define a RESTful technical profile in an Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy.

For *sample*:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserObjID/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$select=displayName
```

[image]

- Pass the object ID of the user as the input claim to the RESTful technical profile.
- Configure it to return the group claim as a string collection.
- And this can be added to the claims to be returned in the token.

**Reference:**

[get group claim in ID token in Azure AD B2c - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/858796/get-group-claim-in-id-token-in-azure-ad-b2c) by AmanpreetSingh-MSFT

Comment: Any solution when we have N groups in the list? Do we need to have N variables to hold them? Is there a way where we can get as a collection of groups? like "groups":[{}]

Comment: Please post it as a new question with all the details including code